# Global variable set in function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var InfoURL

$.get("https://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
    if(response.ip.indexOf(':') > -1) {
        InfoURL = 'google.com';
    } else {
        InfoURL = 'google.ch';  
    } 
    alert(InfoURL);
}, "jsonp");

alert (InfoURL);
```

So why is the second `alert` an empty variable? What must I change so that the variable is global?

Comment: ajax request are async. The second alert actually runs before the `get` finishes.

Comment: By second `alert` you mean first, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `$.get` function is asynchronous, You need to either use promises, or wrap the function into your own function that takes a callback like this:

```
function myGet(callback) {
    $.get("https://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
        if(response.ip.indexOf(':') > -1){
            callback('google.com');
        } else {
            callback ('google.ch');  
        } 
    }, "jsonp")
 }
```

Usage:

```
myGet(function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: So if I want it synchronous which function would it be?

Comment: @mazleu - You don't want it synchronous. That blocks the main thread and the browser may offer the user the option to kill your script. Arrange for the alert to be shown as part of the response processing.

Comment: Your example doesn't work. It says url not defined.